# skip choose user step in Keycloak reset credential flow

Tags: keycloak

In my frontend application, I aim to incorporate a user password update feature. To accomplish this, I redirect the user to the Keycloak update password URL. However, the initial step in the reset credentials flow requires the user to choose a username by entering it manually. I desire to streamline the process by skipping this step entirely and have Keycloak automatically consider the currently logged-in user.

To achieve this, I attempted to customize the reset credentials flow by removing the "Choose User" step. However, this modification resulted in an internal server error. Is there a recommended approach to bypass the "Choose User" step and leverage the currently logged-in user in Keycloak's reset credentials flow?